# SAP Business One Add BP Campaign Using C#

Tags: c#, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I want to generate a campaign of Business Partner in SAP B1 using DIAPI. Can anyone helpme with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Campaign in SAP Business One SDK](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/24/campaign-in-sap-business-one-sdk/) article I can see the following example codes:

**Create a Campaign Document using DI API:**

```
SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsService oCampaignService = oCompany.GetCompanyService().GetBusinessService(SAPbobsCOM.ServiceTypes.CampaignsService);
SAPbobsCOM.Campaign oCampaign = oCampaignService.GetDataInterface(SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsServiceDataInterfaces.csCampaign);
SAPbobsCOM.CampaignParams oCampaignParams = (SAPbobsCOM.CampaignParams)oCampaignService.GetDataInterface(SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsServiceDataInterfaces.csCampaignParams);
oCampaign.TargetGroupType = SAPbobsCOM.TargetGroupTypeEnum.tgtCustomer;
oCampaign.StartDate = DateTime.Today;
oCampaign.FinishDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1);
oCampaign.Remarks = "This is a test for Campaign using DI API.";
oCampaign.CampaignName = "TEST Campaign";
oCampaign.CampaignBusinessPartners.Add().BPCode = "C20000";
oCampaign.CampaignItems.Add().ItemCode = "A00001";
oCampaign.AttachementsEntry = 2; // AbsEntry from the OATC Table
oCampaignService.Add(oCampaign);
```

**Update a Campaign Document using DI API:**

```
SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsService oCampaignService = oCompany.GetCompanyService().GetBusinessService(SAPbobsCOM.ServiceTypes.CampaignsService);
SAPbobsCOM.Campaign oCampaign = oCampaignService.GetDataInterface(SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsServiceDataInterfaces.csCampaign);
SAPbobsCOM.CampaignParams oCampaignParams = (SAPbobsCOM.CampaignParams)oCampaignService.GetDataInterface(SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsServiceDataInterfaces.csCampaignParams);
oCampaignParams.CampaignNumber = 2;
oCampaign = oCampaignService.Get(oCampaignParams);
oCampaign.CampaignItems.Add().ItemCode = "A00002";
oCampaignService.Update(oCampaign);
```

**Cancel a Campaign Document using DI API:**

```
SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsService oCampaignService = oCompany.GetCompanyService().GetBusinessService(SAPbobsCOM.ServiceTypes.CampaignsService);
SAPbobsCOM.Campaign oCampaign = oCampaignService.GetDataInterface(SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsServiceDataInterfaces.csCampaign);
SAPbobsCOM.CampaignParams oCampaignParams = (SAPbobsCOM.CampaignParams)oCampaignService.GetDataInterface(SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsServiceDataInterfaces.csCampaignParams);
oCampaignParams.CampaignNumber = 3;
oCampaignService.Cancel(oCampaignParams);
```

**Remove/Delete a Campaign Document using DI API:**

```
SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsService oCampaignService = oCompany.GetCompanyService().GetBusinessService(SAPbobsCOM.ServiceTypes.CampaignsService);
SAPbobsCOM.Campaign oCampaign = oCampaignService.GetDataInterface(SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsServiceDataInterfaces.csCampaign);
SAPbobsCOM.CampaignParams oCampaignParams = (SAPbobsCOM.CampaignParams)oCampaignService.GetDataInterface(SAPbobsCOM.CampaignsServiceDataInterfaces.csCampaignParams);
oCampaignParams.CampaignNumber = 3;
oCampaignService.Delete(oCampaignParams);
```

Is there something specific you would need help in?